# What would be most correct between 唇に持ち上げた and 唇まで持ち上げた?

Tags: grammar

I'd like to translate a sentence starting as "He lifted the bottle to his lips...". I know both に and まで can be used to indicate destination. I think 彼はボトルを唇に持ち上げた may be better, because the lips are the final destination, however Google Translate gives preference to まで, and I'd like to confirm whether there is a reason for that.

Answer (score 1):

唇に is fine, but 口元に should be more natural (unless the lip is important in the context in some way or another).

唇まで (or 口元まで) is not wrong but it's not the first choice. It adds a nuance of "until it reaches the lip" or something like this. See: [How to use へ (-e), に (-ni), まで (made) and の方 (no-hō) with destination and direction?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/275/5010)