# Why まで and not に?

Tags: particles, particle-に

So I'm reading Chapter 12 (of Minna no Nihongo I) and ran across this sentence:

> 空港**まで**バスと電車とどちらが速いですか。

It's translated as:

> Which is the faster way to get to the airport, by bus or by train?

Why isn't the sentence written this way?

> 空港**に**バスと電車とどちらが速いですか。

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In this type of sentence, `まで` means "all the way to ～" with emphasis on the journey.  The question is asking which is faster to get **to** the airport, but in order to judge this, you have to consider the whole route.  xref [this post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/80/78) for more information.

Answer (score 4):

Basically に is used with a verb, so you can rephrase the sentence with a proper verb, for example 着く. The following sentences have almost the same meaning as the original one using まで.

> 空港にバスと電車とどちらが速く着きますか。
>
> バスと電車のどちらが速く空港に着きますか。(more natural)
>
> 空港に行くのに、バスと電車とどちらが速いですか。

However, you cannot use に to modify a noun (バス or 電車) or an adjective (速い). It is grammatically incorrect. You can say 空港まで速いか but cannot say ×空港に速いか. Also, you can say 空港までのバス but cannot say ×空港にのバス.