# What's the difference between particle へ and を?

Tags: particles, particle-を, particle-へ

Whats the difference between these particles and these two sentences?

1. 国**へ**帰ります
2. 国**を**帰ります

Don't they both mean "I return to the country"?
or

A. おかあさんはみせ**へ**いく。

B. おかあさんはみせ**を**いく。

Are those both correct ways to say "Mom goes to the shop."?

Comment: を is used as a grammatical particle for direct objects, right? I'm very sure you need a location marker, don't you think? Perhaps.

Answer (score 5):

国**を**帰ります and おかあさんはみせ**を**いく are grammatically incorrect as you don't use を for 帰る、行く{いく｝、来る{くる｝、向かう{むかう}、移動{いどう}する、引｛ひ}っ越{こ}す and other similar verbs that indicate movement to another location. For those verbs either へ or に used.

To learn about the difference between へ and に, check this link --> [When going somewhere, is there any difference between e (へ) and ni (に)?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/80/when-going-somewhere-is-there-any-difference-between-e-%E3%81%B8-and-ni-%E3%81%AB)

Comment: It is perfectly grammatical to say 「～～を行く」 if not in 「店を行く」.　https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3243/making-sense-of-transitive-usage-of-%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%8F-and-%E6%9D%A5%E3%82%8B-%E3%82%92%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%8F-and-%E3%82%92%E6%9D%A5%E3%82%8B

Comment: You are right in that を行く is grammatical in the examples on the link you gave. However, if you read my answer in its entirety, I was referring to "verbs that indicate movement to another location" as in the 2 examples that the OP has given. OP meant "I return to the country" and "Mom goes to the shop". This is very clear. Your comment is meant for another case that is not applicable to the OP examples. Too quick to down vote.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that all the verbs included in this answer (with the exception of 移動する only because I don't know) are **intransitive**. The use of を with intransitive verbs is very restricted and to my knowledge can only be used with intransitive verbs that indicate "progressive" movement rather than "instantaneous changes of state". In such cases, を is best thought of as meaning "through" rather than denoting the direct object. [公園を走る]｛こうえんをはしる｝"I'll run through the park."

Comment: @Chcr I have a question about 移動する being intransitive (unless I am mistaken in your implication in which case please correct me). This verb is often used in online shopping sites to convey the concept of "moving items from one list to another". This usage sounds very transitive to me and it seems like 「ＡリストからＢリストにこの商品を 移動す。」 should be a valid and grammatical sentence.  Is this not correct and if so, could you please if not too much trouble provide a similar example of using 移動 correctly in this context? Thanks.