# Should I use the particle に for 学校＿行きます？

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-に, particle-を, particle-で

> 学校＿行きます。
> がっこう＿いきます。

I assume that it does, because で or を doesn't really makes sense. Since で indicates that I'm going in school, and 学校 isn't really a direct object. Or is it?

Comment: 学校**に**行{い}きます or 学校**へ**行{い}きます

Comment: I have already corrected, but the correct kanji for "to go" is 行, not 生. 学校**で**生きます happens to make sense ("I will live **in** the school").

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/80/9831

Answer (score 1):

You can use either に or へ here. As mentioned in @EddieKal's comment, both of the following are correct:

> 学校**に**行きます。
> 学校**へ**行きます。

- this に is "a particle which indicates a place toward which [someone] or [something] moves" [1]
- this へ is "a particle that indicates the direction toward which some directional movement or action proceeds" [2]

In general, you can use the above two interchangeably [3]:

> In actuality, native speakers use へ and に (of point of contact) almost interchangeably except in the case of
>
> ニューヨーク{__}の便はもうありません。
> There isn't any flight to / as far as New York any more.
>
> 〇 ニューヨーク**へ**の便はもうありません。
> 〇 ニューヨーク**まで**の便はもうありません。
> ✖ ニューヨーク**に**の便はもうありません。(に cannot be followed by の)

An example:

> 東京**に**十二時に着いた。
> 東京**へ**十二時に着いた。
> I arrived in Tokyo at 12:00 o'clock.

---

<sub>[1] A Dictionary of Basic Japanese Grammar p. 302 (ni<sup>7</sup> に)</sub>
<sub>[2] A Dictionary of Basic Japanese Grammar p. 116 (e へ)</sub>
<sub>[3] A Dictionary of Basic Japanese Grammar p. 117 (e へ Related Expressions section I)</sub>

Answer (score -1):

学校へ行きます is more common.

When using "へ" you are referring to a place/direction, while "に" you could use for other verbs.

- その目的地へと（行く）。
- その目的地に何かありましたっけ？

People often use に because they are assuming they are entering the building "School".

Go to cinema:

- 映画館へ行く。Correct.
- 映画館に行く。Correct.(Edited)

Entering the car:

- 車へ入る。Not common.
- 車に入る。Correct.

Comment: Why is 映画館に行く wrong?  Could you explain that?

Comment: 学校へ行きます and 学校に行きます both sound equally formal to me. Do you have a supporting source for this? Additionally, based on A Dictionary of Basic Japanese Grammar page 117 (for the particle へ) which says, "Even the *ni* of direct contact meaning 'into; onto' can be replaced by *e* as in: お風呂 **に** / **へ** 入った (Lit. I entered into a bath. (=I took a bath.))", I would say that 車へ入る is also a correct way of saying "entering a car".

Comment: In this case, see this link:
https://kawakawalearningstudio.com/all/how-to-differentiate-location-particles-%E3%81%A7de-%E3%81%ABni-and-%E3%81%B8e/

Comment: ^ Hmm.. that website Kawa Kawa Learning Studio doesn't seem to be that reliable. I viewed several pages of theirs and found them giving some incorrect/unnatural examples/translations, eg「彼のアドバイスに聞く。」「彼のアドバイスに聞かないでください。」とか... あんまり鵜呑みにしない方がいいと思いますよ…

Comment: 彼のアドバイスに聞く。
People don't ask to advice, but ask for advice.
彼のアドバイスについて聞く。彼のアドバイスを聞く。

Comment: ?? In my previous comment I said: Some of KawaKawa's example sentences are incorrect, for example, 「彼のアドバイスに聞く。」「彼のアドバイスに聞かないでください。」  [given here in their page](https://kawakawalearningstudio.com/japanese/jlpt-n3-grammar-you-need-to-know-how-to-use-%ef%bd%9e%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84%e3%81%a7-%ef%bd%9e%e3%81%9a-and-%ef%bd%9e%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84%e3%81%86%e3%81%a1%e3%81%ab/), so I wouldn't really recommend trusting their pages.